# Docker: How to solve the public key error in ubuntu while installing docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am getting the below error message when running the below command for installing docker and kubernetes in Ubuntu server.

```
root@master:/home/ubuntu# add-apt-repository \
>   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
>   $(lsb_release -cs) \
>   stable"
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease [64.4 kB]
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
**Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8**
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
**E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.**
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@master:/home/ubuntu#
```

I have also ran the below command but no luck

```
root@master:/# sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.rDOuMCVLF2/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

## EDIT: This answer apparently does not work any more

Run this to add the correct key:

```
# Does not work any more
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

Comment: As of now, the docker instructions fail to identify that their newer instructions only work on Ubuntu 20.04(?) and newer.  They now say to pipe to a gpg --dearmor command, which will not work under Ubuntu 18.04 and many earlier versions.  Instead the apt-key add needs to be used.

Comment: You guys may want to check my answer, which you'll need in case your umask creates unreadable files.

Comment: In the source they are advicing to do: `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg` isn't it correct any more?

Comment: Doesn's work.
`$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg`
 



`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

Answer (score 65):

I had this exact problem.  I believe it was caused by my default umask, which caused some of the Docker files to be installed with incorrect permissions.  I was able to fix it by correcting the file permissions the docker key file:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Comment: You saved my day, I confirmed this with `strace -f apt update 2>&1|grep key|grep docker-archive-keyring`, see my reply below.

Comment: I feel like apt-get should issue a warning message if some keys are unreadable.

Comment: This answer saved my day too! Thanks a lot, using `sudo apt-get update` now works again.

Comment: This answer worked where others didn't.

Comment: The only answer that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 61):

**First**, add Docker’s official GPG key:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor --yes -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

or in other cases (macOS)

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor --yes -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

PS For some the part `gpgp --dearmor` was useful.

**Second**, update permissions for it:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
```

or in other cases (macOS)

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

<kbd>[Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu - Official Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)</kbd>

Comment: The permission granting did it for me! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @HumbleBee Good)

Comment: The `gpgp --dearmor` part was essential for me. This should be the marked answer, thanks

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni Good!)

Comment: The key needs to be in `/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg` now, not the location in this answer

Comment: Even then though it still fails because `because the public key is not available`

Comment: @DouglasGaskell I updated the answer by using `/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg`

Comment: Tried few workarounds. Finally this worked. Seems I need to remove earlier few workaround entries from Ubuntu.

Comment: The permission update worked for me.

Answer (score 36):

There is issue with Debian Testing (bullseye):

> Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

But can be solved with:

```
 curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Comment: This didn't work for me: with my default umask, the file was install without read permissions, causing the exact same behavior above.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 Google Cloud instance

Comment: your curl command fix my issue AT LAST :D ... thanks

Comment: Indeed for me too this was the answer I needed on Ubuntu 20.04 (Debian) to resolve the error `Err :7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease` `NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8`.
After this do `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 17):

from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
It works in ubuntu 20.04

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Comment: With 20.04 LTS (codename focal) the error from above is "gpg: conflicting commands     (23) Failed writing body"

Comment: The answer that worked for  me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS: `echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
`.
This line got updated on the docker website and for unknown reason weren't working with my OS version (20.04).

Comment: Confirmed working for me on `Ubuntu 22 jammy` --
Error: `Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8`

Answer (score 9):

Make sure /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg is global readable.

```
# ls -l /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
-rw-rw---- 1 root root 2760 Aug 17 06:46 /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
strace -f apt update 2>&1 | grep docker-archive-keyring
[pid  9453] faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", R_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
# chmod o+r /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
# strace -f apt update 2>&1 | grep docker-archive-keyring
[pid  9772] faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", R_OK) = 0
[pid  9795] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid  9795] access("/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", F_OK) = 0
[pid  9795] access("/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", R_OK) = 0
[pid  9795] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid  9795] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", O_RDONLY) = 7
[pid  9795] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg", O_RDONLY) = 8
```

Comment: worked for me, too

Answer (score 8):

Here's the error

`W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8`

Copy the key that follows `NO_PUBKEY` and do

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys <the key>
```

Make sure you replace `<the key>` with the key you copied
And then run your command again

Comment: Did you check that Ubuntu keyserver indeed has the needed key?

Comment: This didnt work for me

Answer (score 8):

For 22.04 I had to do:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.gpg
```

specifically, get the output to go to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.gpg

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too (22.04). Also had to update the next command to this:

`$ echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

There're many reasons why you can get the "public key is not available" and most of them are listed above. However I recently had an unexpected one.

I believe somewhere between 20.04 and 22.04 there was a change in the apt behavior. Both versions support armored gpg keys (true since 1.4, around 2017). But there's a difference:

1. In 20.04 apt v2.0 ACCEPTS an armored key from a file with the `.gpg` extension
2. In 22.04 apt v2.4 IGNORES armored keys if they have a `.gpg` extension. It requires them to have an `.asc` or `.pub` extension instead.

It was a bit puzzling when a tested and stable ansible playbook installing docker stopped working after switching to 22.04. Changing the file extension fixed the issue.

Comment: Can confirm.  Incredibly frustrating change.

Comment: it also ignores unarmoured keys if they have .asc extension

Answer (score 2):

If you did followed the Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu steps, Please see your permissions file `/usr/share/keyrings/`.

It should be `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.7K Sep 13 05:46 docker-archive-keyring.gpg`

`-rw-r--r--`

I changed permissions before it `-rw-r-----` into `-rw-r--r--`
by using this command

```
sudo chmod o+r /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

And then check it by using apt update, it's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 20.04, this is what you should do:

`echo \ "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`

**INSTEAD OF**

`echo \"deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null`

On the [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository), this line got updated and `/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg` became `/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg`.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this issue while installing docker in Ubuntu 22.04.
While I did not take the time to understand what I was missing, I found this link to have helped with this. [Install docker in ubuntu 22.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Running WSL Ubuntu 22.04.

Not sure why, but it seems to be not be happy with the save location. Changing it from `/etc/apt/keyrings/` -> `/usr/share/keyrings` makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was necessary to check that the repositories were correctly specified in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

Specifically, in my case I removed the file: `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/download_docker_com_linux_ubuntu.list`.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by tuomassalo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61058103/4430246) is not relevant for Ubuntu 22.04 and later as `apt-key` utility is obsolete since the latest LTS release. Thus If any one wants to fix the issue with the keys it would be better using `gpg` and address file to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/[file_name.gpg]` using command like:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/docker.gpg
```

pay attension that `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` dir is responsible for repo shared keys not `/etc/apt/keyrings/`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a non-supported OS version of Ubuntu (14.04.6 LTS). Make sure to compare your OS version with the supported version as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#os-requirements

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here because I was trying to install Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.1 by adding their repo to the apt config. I was setting up an ansible playbook to do this.

Like many others above, I was having problems with the `The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...**` error.

I eventually settled on the following piece of ansible to get the job done:

```
    - name: setting up docker apt repo
      block:
        - name: get docker gpg key
          become: true
          get_url:
            url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
            dest: /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring-armored.gpg
        - name: CMD - process docker key
          become: true
          shell:
            cmd: cat /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring-armored.gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
        - name: configure docker apt source
          become: true        
          apt_repository:
            repo: "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_release }} stable"
            state: present
```

Putting this here for the next poor sod that wants to make this go.

Answer (score 0):

In file sources.list ->
in the line where the repository is specified, you need to add an entry before the address (in square brackets)

[arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker-archive-keyrings.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stable

Answer (score 0):

If you are using debian repository in your Docker image, it may be issue related to GPG (GNU Privacy Gaurd) signatures, it may also related to repository's GPU keys or local keyrings used for signature verifications

#Refreshing GPG Keys may resolve the issue

`RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y debian-archive-keyring && apt-get clean`